# What is the best database structure for this situation?

Tags: database, django, postgresql

I'm writing a stock manager with these tables:

- harvest
- sale and purchase
- customer and producer
- sale_item and purchase_item
- and others

I would like to know what the best way to organize the tables.

My main question is how create the `sales` and `purchase`, because they have almost the same fields but `customer` and `producer` are totally different.

I thought of two options. The first is duplicate fields in `sale`, in `purchase`, in `sale_item` and in `purchase_item`. The second is to create a table named `order` and one column to store a type (`sale` or `purchase`), do the same with `sale_item` and `purchase_item`, and create a table named `person` with other tables named `customer` and `producer` that inherit `person`.

What the best approach?

I am using Django with Postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably separate sale and purchase into two separate tables (and sale_item and purchase_item.) Even though they have duplicate columns -- for now -- they represent separate concepts.

In the future, it's easy to imagine that either of those concepts could change in some way so that the underlying tables would *not* have all the same columns.

Having two separate sets of tables also makes it easier to query.

Comment: I almost used up all your tip. I just mix with @johnbarr 's tip representing the `sale_item` and `purchase_item` by the same Django model but in database is two different tables.

Answer (score 0):

Normalizing the tables according to your entities is the right approach.

Additionally, I would think about the probability that you'd want those entities presented together, merged, in the same list view.

Looking at the entities you are referring to, I think sale_item and purchase_item have high probability to be used interchangeably, so I would put then in the same table.